# Create Enumerable In Place Slice Of Array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, collections, enumerator

I'm looking to find a way to take an array in ruby, two indices in that array and return an enumerable object which will yield, in order, all the elements between and including the two indices. But for performance reasons, I want to do this subject to the following two conditions:

- This slice to enum does not create a copy of the subarray I want a return an enum over. This rules out `array[i..j].to_enum`, for example because `array[i..j]` is creating a new array.
- It's not necessary to loop over the entire array to create the enum.

I'm wondering if there's a way to do this using the standard library's enumerable or array functionality without having to explicitly create my own custom enumerator.

What I'm looking for is a cleaner way to create the below enumerator:

```
def enum_slice(array, i, j)
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    while i <= j
      y << array[i] # this is confusing syntax for yield (see here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerator.html#method-c-new)
      i += 1
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

That seems pretty reasonable, and could even be turned into an extension to Array itself:

```
module EnumSlice
  def enum_slice(i, j)
    Enumerator.new do |y|
      while i <= j
        y << self[i]
        i += 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now within the `Enumerator` block, `y` represents a `Proc` you call when you have more data. If that block ends it's presumed you're done enumerating. There's no requirement to ever terminate, an infinite Enumerator is allowed, and in that case it's up to the caller to stop iterating.

So in other words, the `y` block argument can be called *zero or more times*, and each time it's called output is "emitted" from the enumerator. When that block exits the enumerator is considered done and is closed out, `y` is invalid at that point.

All `y << x` does is call the `<<` method on [`Enumerator::Yielder`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator/Yielder.html), which is a bit of syntactical sugar to avoid having to do `y.call(x)` or `y[x]`, both of which look kind of ugly.

Now you can add this to Array:

```
Array.include(EnumSlice)
```

Where now you can do stuff like this:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ].enum_slice(2, 4).each do |v|
  p v
end
```

Giving you the correct output.

It's worth noting that despite having gone through all this work, this really doesn't save you any time. There's already built-in methods for this. Your `enum_slice(a, i, j)` method is equivalent to:

```
a.drop(i).take(j)
```

Is that close in terms of performance? A a quick benchmark can help test that theory:

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  count = 10000
  a = (0..100_000).to_a

  bm.report(:enum_slice) do
    count.times do
      a.enum_slice(50_000, 25_000).each do
      end
    end
  end
  bm.report(:drop_take) do
    count.times do
      a.drop(50_000).take(25_000).each do
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The results are:

```
       user     system      total        real
enum_slice  0.020536   0.000200   0.020736 (  0.020751)
drop_take  7.682218   0.019815   7.702033 (  7.720876)
```

So your approach is about 374x faster. Not bad!